# How do I exclude the zeros from outputting in my array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code. I would like to only display the parts of the array that are greater than 0. 
For example... A bunch of numbers are entered and stored as a variable. But not all of the variables in the array will be used. The ones that aren't are stored as 0. So when I display the array, the numbers are displayed as:
"140, 180, 298, 130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, " etc. 
I don't want the zeros to be displayed.

```
int[] scores = {score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8, score9, score10, score11, score12, score13, score14, score15};

Console.WriteLine("Your scores as you entered them: " + (string.Join(", ", scores)));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Having 15 variable like this I suspect you might be able to use a loop somewhere and already place them in a list in the first place instead of in separate variables

Comment: Consider using a `List<int>`, which will grow as you add to it, rather than an array which is fixed in size and therefore contains zeros.

Comment: Please accept one answer as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use linq's `Where`:

```
string.Join(", ", scores.Where(x => x != 0))
```

In the description above you also said *the parts of the array that are greater than 0*. So if that is the case you can change it to:

```
string.Join(", ", scores.Where(x => x > 0))
```

---

For a non linq solution use a `List<int>` and a simple foreach (or for) loop:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach(int item in scores)
{
    if(item != 0)
        result.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Please remove non LinQ solution. Because answer is crystal clear.

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ - no need to remove the non linq because even though I think the linq one is the way to go, if this is too advanced for OP then that is a simpler version

Comment: @Michael M - Glad it helped

Comment: Thanks @GiladGreen! I appreciate it!

Comment: I did decide to go with the non linq answer. I'm very new to programming and have no clue what that is! So thank you @GiladGreen for not removing it.

Comment: @MichaelM - Good :) when you feel a bit more secure I do recommend reading into linq - it is the most convenient tool for manipulating collections :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't understand `LINQ` yet, you can look into this piece of code:

```
int[] scores = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 6};

int[] withoutZeros = WithoutZeros (scores);
```

And the core method:

```
public static int[] WithoutZeros (int[] input)
{
    int zerosCount = 0; // we need to count how many zeros are in the input array

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == 0) zerosCount = zerosCount + 1;
    }

    // now we know number of zeros, so we can create output array
    // which will be smaller than then input array (or not, if we don't have any zeros in the input array)

    int[] output = new int[input.Length - zerosCount]; // can be smaller, equal, or even empty

    // no we need to populate non-zero values from the input array to the output array

    int indexInOutputArray = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] != 0)
        {
            output[indexInOutputArray] = input[i];

            indexInOutputArray = indexInOutputArray + 1;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: There are simpler ways for a non linq solution.. Also consider using the `++` operator instead of `x = x + 1`

Comment: Yes, And also many bugs "non LinQ solution". I should not prefer to count them.

Answer (score 0):

To get the answer of your question have a look at Gilad Green's answer.

I just wanted to give you a little feedback about the code I see.

Since, I dont see all your code I am making a lot of assumptions here, so sorry if I am wrong.

If you want to fill an array with 15 values, you should consider refactoring your code to use a loop.

In the following example I will use a `for` loop but it could be solved with different loops.

```
int[] scores = new int[15]; //initialize an array of ints with a length of 15
for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++) //loop from 0 till smaller than the length of the array (0-14 = 15 iterations)
    scores[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //fill the scores array with the index of i with the console input
```